# How to save nested JSON data into Elasticsearch from Apache Nifi?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

When I try to insert `geo_shape` type entry into Elasticsearch from Apache Nifi. This is just a nested JSON field - for eaxmple, in Apache Nifi my FlowFile have this nested content for `geo_shape`:

```
{ 
    "location": "{\"type\":\"polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[3.042514,41.79673582],[3.04182089,41.79738937],[3.04299467,41.79763732],[3.042514,41.79673582]]]}"
}
```

In Elasticsearch the field is specified as follows:

```
"location": {
   "type": "geo_shape"
}
```

When I execute `PutElasticsearch1.3`, I get the following error:

> MapperParsingException failed to parse [location]: nested - shape must
>   be an object consisting of type and coordinates

How can I parse this nested JSON string in order to save it in Elasticsearch from Apache Nifi?

Comment: check  AttributesToJSON, JoltTransformJSON, and EvaluateJsonPath processors. btw, the value of `location` in your json seems to be json encoded into string.. and if you want to extract `polygon` you need to double parse (two EvaluateJsonPath). or you can try ExecuteScript processor.

Comment: @daggett: yes, this is the json encoded string. Finally I solved this issue using `ExecuteScript` as follows: `"location_field": json.loads(obj['location'])`